# Vim/Syntastic: Cannot "from ... import ..." but can "import ... as ..."

Tags: vim, syntastic

I am using 1) Vi Improved 7.4 & 2) Syntastic syntax-checker for vim.

When I tried to import the "sklearn.metrics" module to use the 
"pairwise_distances" functions,
`from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances` works in both the 'python' & 'python3' terminal mode.

However, the same line caused: `foo.py|8 col 1 error| [import-error] Unable to import 'sklearn.metrics'` when I put it in a .py file and opened with `vim foo.py`. Yet executing the file with `python3 foo.py` did not report any error.

I also tried another way to import the module by doing `import sklearn.metrics as sk_met` and call `sk_met.pairwise_distances(...)` in the body of my code. This works for all the aforementioned methods ('python', 'python3', 'vim foo.py'). It seem to me vim can find "sklearn.metrics" just fine, but not through `from ... import`.

Could it be the syntax checker's problem?

[image]

Comment: Syntastic is just a framework, it doesn't know, nor cares, about the contents of your files. Find out which _checker_ complains about your code. Also, read the [FAQ entry](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqpython) about using syntastic to check both Python 2 and Python 3 code.

Comment: But shouldn't "import ... as ..." behave the same way "from ... import ..." do in terms of whether a module exists and can be imported?

Comment: Err, find out which _checker_ complains about your code?